# Resuming a thread on another machine from the current JVM stack

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, distributed-computing, distributed

On the JVM, I run a thread and at some point I block it. If I persist the JVM thread stack at this point, and all the objects I explicitly created in my code that it refers to (I assume they are all serializable), will it be feasible to use this data to resume the thread on another JVM?

Are there any frameworks/libraries out there that can help me or get me closer to doing such a thing?

Comment: Nope. The stack trace you get from the Thread methods doesn't contain enough information. At best it's source-line resolution, but it should be VM program counter. And I'm quite sure there's no API for establishing a method-call stack without really doing the nested method calls.

Comment: Probably the practical details are difficult to overcome, but conceptually, if I have the same workflow available in the other JVM, if I know the point in the workflow where I paused, and if I save the state of the workflow when I paused - isn't it all what I need in order to resume the execution on another JVM?

Comment: I think quasar does some magic to move around stacks, but that's only within the same JVM. Doing that between JVMs might be possible in theory, maybe through debugging interfaces. but would probably be quite fragile and I am not aware of any implementation.

Comment: If you can express the entire application state, including the ongoing/pending operations, as a (serializable) object graph, there is no need to copy and restore thread stacks. All you need, is an operation (a method) that will resume the pending operations given an application state object (graph). An application state expressed as object graph, is the norm for Desktop/GUI applications. They usually resume on incoming events, which will be handled based on the even data and the state of the objects, rather than having stopped threads to resume.

Comment: @Holger could you point out a concrete example/link?